# android custom camera crash with fail to connect to camera service

Tags: android, camera

Sorry if my Question is kind of noob, just beginning to delve into Android prog. I tried to run the custom camera code taken from [github](https://github.com/devcelebi/Kut-Camera)

However, the app crash upon run. Logcat: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service` indicates that it is due to the camera permission. I already added the camera permission in the android manifest file before, it is still showing same error.

I added permission in the android manifest as shown below;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try another camer. If it doesn't work - restart device. If it works, you probably need to check which camera(front/back) it tries to use and if this camera exists.

Comment: i tested this on the android emulator. Same thing happened when i tested on real device too..

Comment: Forget about emulator. It doesn't work properly with camera. Try doing what I wrote

Comment: Thanks Sam, I tried on another device, and it worked properly. Weird that it wasn't working on my test device , my old rooted nexus 4. So, i can safely assume from now on that the anything related to camera might/might not work on the android emulator.